# Code Contracts- Invariants are not rewritten

Tags: c#, .net, runtime, code-contracts, invariants

I am using VS2010 Ultimate with Code Contracts.  After getting unexpected runtime behavior, I reviewed the source code in reflector and realized that my invariants are not being compiled.  The generated `__ContractsRuntime` class only contains definitions for `Assert`, `Ensures`, `ReportFailure`, `Requires<TException>` and `TriggerFailure`.  I am using the `[ContractInvariantMethodAttribute]` over a single private method per type for all my `Contract.Invariant(...)` clauses.  I have full contract checking with "Standard Contract Requires" configured as the assembly mode.

My assembly file contains the following assembly attribute:

```
[assembly: RuntimeContracts(RuntimeContractsFlags.InheritContracts | RuntimeContractsFlags.StandardMode | RuntimeContractsFlags.ThrowOnFailure | RuntimeContractsFlags.Assumes | RuntimeContractsFlags.Asserts | RuntimeContractsFlags.Invariants | RuntimeContractsFlags.Ensures | RuntimeContractsFlags.Requires | RuntimeContractsFlags.RequiresWithException | RuntimeContractsFlags.LegacyRequires)]`
```

Does anyone have this issue or any insight as to why my invariants are not working as expected?

Comment: Try to post a minimal sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @HenkHolterman what do you want to see?  The reflected/generated code? Or my code?

Comment: A complete reproducible sample. As small as possible.